# $_SESSION not working on my php code

Tags: php, mysql, session

The 'Welcome guest' and the user's email should appear at the header, but it seems like there's something in my code. And also all throughout my php code with 'customer_email' which is coming from the database, an error keeps on pushing me to review the page. The error is

**Here's the code for the customer_email:**

```
<?php
                $user = $_SESSION['customer_email'];

                $get_img = "select * from customers where customer_email='$user'";

                $run_img = mysqli_query($con, $get_img);

                $row_img = mysqli_fetch_array($run_img);

                $c_img = $row_img['customer_img'];

                $c_name = $row_img['customer_name'];
        ?>
```

**Here's the code for the Welcome guest:**

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['customer_name'])){
        echo "<b style='color:yellow;'>Welcome:</b>" . $_SESSION['customer_name'] ;
    }
    else{
        echo "";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Look up the command `session_start()` then use it in every script that requires access to the `$_SESSION` [Here is a link to the manual, try using it often](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Comment: I already added that in all of my page @RiggsFolly

Comment: Well you didn't add it in the example script you showed to us. _We cannot debug what we cannot see_ **Nobody here is clairvoyant**

Comment: it looks like the error is occouring on My_account,.php and you state welcome guest as the landing page. Are you showing the right code to us?

Comment: how about the 'customer_email' ? It is always the problem in all of my page mentioning 'customer_email' @RiggsFolly

Comment: yes that's the right code. @Juakali92

Comment: update your question rather than write code in comments please

Comment: I added session_start() in all of my page.

Comment: Add a `print_r($_SESSION);` directly after the `session_start()` to see what is actually in your session

Comment: @Juakali92 Note error on line 213, and he shows us 6 lines of code. this is not debuggings guess work

Comment: it says array() @RiggsFolly

Comment: So your session has not had anything loaded into it, or maybe it has expired

Comment: Check your code, where do you do something to load the session `$_SESSION['customer_name'] = $something`

Comment: what do you mean it has expired? is there anything I can do with that? @RiggsFolly

Comment: That is the most unlikely reason, check that you actually set `$_SESSION['customer_name']` somewhere in your code

Comment: I can't fix it @RiggsFolly still in the same error

Comment: Sorry I cannot fix what I cannot see

Comment: how did you fill `$_SESSION['customer_name']` with its values? @Drx

Comment: customer_name is from my database @JanLeeYu

Comment: I mean this one `$_SESSION['customer_email'];`

Comment: it's also from my database, $user will fetch the value of customer_email @JanLeeYu .

Comment: what happens when you echoed it? like `echo $_SESSION['customer_email'];`

Comment: if echoed it the value of customer_email should appear which was passed to $user.

Comment: what is the actual output.